# ui-router url params with a hierarchy

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

how is it possible to set up url routes in the $stateProvider of the ui-router module with url params in a hierarchy like this

```
/home  
/:username  
/:title/editor
```

I only get it to work if there is no conflict on the same hierarchy level like:

```
/home  
/user/:username  
/editor/:title
```

Right now everything will router to `/home` if I try to set it up like in the first example.

I know it from other situations like on Google Appengine, where the first approach would work aswell and where it would be seen as a kind of hierarchy, where the `/:username` route would apply as long it not equals 'home'.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I would say this should be possible, e.g. this would work (see [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/xlvC0ZNWAfLChwrLYSLs?p=preview)):

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'test.html',
    controller: 'TestCtrl',
  })
  .state('editor', {
    url: '/:title/editor',
    ...
  })
  .state('user', {
    url: '/:userName',
    ...
```

Observe it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xlvC0ZNWAfLChwrLYSLs?p=preview). The reason why this is working, because the state editor - with a strong key **`/editor`** is evaluated before `userName`. The same for home - it is the first evaluated pattern.

*BUT - I would suggest, do not count on order. Use these discriminators at the beginning (e.g. /user/... or /editor/..). Our users, will understand it as well, and any later confusion (why this url triggered that state) won't surprise us*

Comment: Great if that helped. Enjoy `ui-router`!